# How to remove Upi(External wallet) from Razorpay - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, razorpay, flutter-razorpay

I am using Razorpay for the payment in an e- commerce app, Actually in only need card payment in the payment method of razorpay. But how can i remove all the external payment from the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the payment methods of your choice on the Checkout section of the Payment Links to provide a highly personalized experience for your customers.

```
curl -u [YOUR_KEY_ID]:[YOUR_KEY_SECRET] \
-X POST https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payment_links/ \
-H 'Content-type: application/json' \
-d '{
  "amount": 1000,
  "currency": "INR",
  "accept_partial": true,
  "first_min_partial_amount": 100,
  "reference_id": "#523442",
  "description": "Payment for policy no #23456",
  "customer": {
    "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
    "contact": "+919999999999",
    "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com"
  },
  "notify": {
    "sms": true,
    "email": true
  },
  "reminder_enable": true,
  "options": {
    "checkout": {
      "method": {
        //here you have to specify
        "netbanking": "1",
        "card": "1",
        "upi": "0",
        "wallet": "0"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**Edit**
official docs: https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/

Comment: can you provide more information to configure this in flutter.